# Can not validate the field properly using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to validate properly the input field as per user requirement using AngularJS.

I am providing my code below:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.longitude.$touched && billdata.longitude.$invalid }">
  <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Longitude coordinate" ng-model="longitude" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/" ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');">
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.longitude.$error" ng-if="billdata.longitude.$touched">
  <p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs only number(e.g-0,1..9).</p>
</div>
```

Here requirement is user can entry number only with `+` or `-` like this `i.e-+123.45 or -095.4567`. In current case the `+` or `-` is not allowed only numbers are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow corresponding symbols in regexp

```
ng-pattern="/^(\+|-)?[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/"
```

Comment: @satya They aren't. That's why there is `?` after the group. `/^(\+|-)?[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/.test('6.89'); //true`

Answer (score 0):

ng-pattern="/^([+|-][[0-9]+([,.][0-9]{n,m}))]?$/";

try using this just replace n and m with minimum number of decimal places ie in ur case be 0 and m with highest number of decimal places allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can write own directive for custom validation like below one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div>
      <form novalidate name="myForm">
        Number: <input type="text" name="valText" ng-model="val" even-number />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span style="color: red;" ng-show="myForm.valText.$error.evenNumber">Invalid value</span>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button ng-click="setValue(22)">Change Value to 22</button>
      <br />
      <button ng-click="setValue(19)">Change Value to 19</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ld0ZfVvMLoQPm5lDHMbS?p=preview).

This Even Number directive, only even number is allowed.